# Grails - error/exception: No module found with name [export]

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I have installed Grails plugin export (s. http://grails.org/plugin/export) successfully in my Grails (version 2.2.1) web application developing on Intellij plattform. All my downloaded plugins are in the separate "Plugins" folder, export plugin too.

```
When I run my application i get the following error:
Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <r:layoutResources>: No module found with name [export]
The relevant content of my *.gsp-view:
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
        <r:require module="export"/>
        <g:layoutHead/>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </head> 
<body>
<div>
<export:formats formats="['csv', 'excel', 'ods', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'xml']" />
</div>
</body>

What may be the cause of the error/exception?
```

Comment: Try to refresh dependencies by `grails refresh-dependencies` command from command line

Comment: you need to make sure, that the module "export" is defined in your resources-config, as the exception suggests :)